# How do I install PIP in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a fresh install of python 3.5 on my windows PC
and here is my directory of my installation:
C:\Users*PCNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

I have installed it entering python get-pip.py in CMD, it says it is installed successfully but when I enter pip in CMD it says it is not recognized?

Please kindly enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory `{Your python root dir}\Scripts`

Then press `Shift + Right CLick > Open CMD here`

Then type in `pip install {package name}`